# customized listview in xamarin android

Tags: android, listview, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am creating a customized list in **xamarin android**

Here is my code:

```html
using System;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace FinalList
{
 [Activity (Label = "FinalList", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
 public class MainActivity :ListActivity
 {
  string[] items;
  protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
  {  
  
   base.OnCreate (bundle);
   items = new string[] { "aBulbs","bFliuits","cFruits","dpriraji","eqsbciob","frTubers","guhVegetables","hvwert","iwxamarin","jyaaaa","kVegetables","lFruits","mVegetables","nwert","pxamarin","ryaaaa"};
   //ListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, items);
   ListView lv =FindViewById<ListView> (Android.Resource.Id.List);
   ListAdapter = new HomeScreenAdapter(this, items);
   ListView.FastScrollEnabled = true;
   //listview.ChoiceMode = Android.Widget.ChoiceMode.Single;
     // listview.SetItemChecked (1, true);
   lv.SetItemChecked (3, true);
  }
  protected override void OnListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
  {
   var t = items[position];
   Android.Widget.Toast.MakeText(this, t, Android.Widget.ToastLength.Short).Show();
  }
 }
}
```

This is my axml file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
   <ListView
     android:id="@+id/List"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
     />
</LinearLayout>
```

and here is my `HomeScreenAdapter` file:

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

namespace FinalList
{
 [Activity (Label = "HomeScreenAdapter")]   
 public class HomeScreenAdapter : BaseAdapter<string>,ISectionIndexer {
  String[] items;
  Activity context;
  Dictionary<string, int> alphaIndex;
  String[] sections;
  Java.Lang.Object[] sectionsObjects;
  public HomeScreenAdapter(Activity context, string[] items) : base() {
   this.context = context;
   this.items = items;
    alphaIndex = new Dictionary<string, int>();
   for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++) { // loop through items
    String s = items [i];
    String key = s.Substring (0, 1);
    key= key.ToUpper ();
    if (!alphaIndex.ContainsKey(key))
     alphaIndex.Add(key, i); // add each 'new' letter to the index
   }
   sections = new string[alphaIndex.Keys.Count];
   alphaIndex.Keys.CopyTo(sections, 0); // convert letters list to string[]
   // Interface requires a Java.Lang.Object[], so we create one here
    sectionsObjects = new Java.Lang.Object[sections.Length];
   for (int i = 0; i < sections.Length; i++) {
    sectionsObjects[i] = new Java.Lang.String(sections[i]);
   }
  }
  public override long GetItemId(int position)
  {
   return position;
  }
  public override string this[int position] {  
   get { return items[position]; }
  }
  public override int Count {
   get { return items.Length; }
  }
  public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
  {
   View view = convertView; // re-use an existing view, if one is available
   if (view == null) // otherwise create a new one
    view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItemChecked, null);
   view.FindViewById<TextView>(Android.Resource.Id.Text1).Text = items[position];
   return view;
  }
  public Java.Lang.Object[] GetSections()
  {
   return sectionsObjects;
  }
  public int GetPositionForSection(int section)
  {
   return alphaIndex[sections[section]];
  }
  public int GetSectionForPosition(int position)
  {      // this method isn't called in this example, but code is provided for completeness
   int prevSection = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < sections.Length; i++)
   {
    if (GetPositionForSection(i) > position)
    {
     break;
    }
    prevSection = i;
   }
   return prevSection;
  }


 }
}
```

When I build solution I get **null object reference exception**
It says:

```
object reference is not set to an instance of an object at line
lv.setitemchecked(1,true);
```

How do I remove this exception?

Answer (score 1):

You have to inflate your layout in your Activity just after your `base.OnCreate (bundle);` :

```
SetContentView(Resource.Layout."YourLayoutName");
```

Comment: when i try to inflate my layout it also gives an exception.

Comment: But you need to inflate the layout, can you post your code and the exception pls ?

Comment: actually in xamarin when we create customized list we do not need to explicitly inflate our layout.if we try to do so then there appears an exception that attribute with id lv is not there

Answer (score 0):

you should use

```
ListView lv =FindViewById<ListView> (Android.Resource.Id.List);
        ListAdapter = new HomeScreenAdapter(this, items);
        lv.FastScrollEnabled = true;
        //lv.ChoiceMode = Android.Widget.ChoiceMode.Single;
       // lv.SetItemChecked (1, true);
        lv.SetItemChecked (3, true);
```

instead of

```
ListView lv =FindViewById<ListView> (Android.Resource.Id.List);
        ListAdapter = new HomeScreenAdapter(this, items);
        ListView.FastScrollEnabled = true;
        //listview.ChoiceMode = Android.Widget.ChoiceMode.Single;
       // listview.SetItemChecked (1, true);
        lv.SetItemChecked (3, true);
```

remember to setContentView(resource.layout.your_layout);  too